# how to save only time in database without date

Tags: datetime, c#-4.0

How to save only time of day in database without saving date?
I am trying this statement but its save date and time:

```
    DateTime time= Convert.ToDateTime(rec.InOutTimes[i].entry.Value.ToShortDateString(),null)
```

Comment: Use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.aspx) type, and not the datetime.

Comment: TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second);

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value as seconds or milliseconds, then use Timespan.

```
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
int millis = interval.TotalMilliseconds;
```